# Access APIs from using mobile app from local server

Tags: android, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have built an app using ionic that uses some APIs. Running local server I successfully accessed those API from mobile browser i.e. Google Chrome. But when I build the app and ran on mobile, using the same URL as I entered on browser, the app is unable to access those API. It throws some error like this:

> Runtime Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid
>   URL

I used the URL as: [192.168.88.195:8080/rbs0.0.1/api/tableList][1]

Using the same URL APIs are successfully accessed from mobile browser and my problem is when I build app and run on android, app shows error as I mentioned above. What's the reason?? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you log the api url?

Comment: Yeah, it shows the URL as I have mentioned above when running in android emulator.

Comment: Try adding 'http' to the address

Comment: you mean, the URL is accessible through browser but not through app? If so, check if you have requested `"android.permission.INTERNET"` permission

Comment: Is your API external or running on a local server on the same machine?

Comment: @Chris, valid query.